# select data based on the array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array from query like below:

```
array:84 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "comp" => "50007148"
        "cus" => "F0401"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "comp" => "50007148"
        "cus" => "J0050"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [
        "comp" => "50007148"
        "cus" => "L"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [
        "comp" => "50007148"
        "cus" => "LT"
      ]
      4 => array:2 [
        "comp" => "50007148"
        "cus" => "RP"
      ]
```

Now I need to write a query where comp, cus in above query.

```
$rslt = Stdetl::whereIn('comp, cus', $categories)
                           ->where(YEAR(docdate), '=', 2019)
                           ->get(SUM(number))->toArray();
```

But this query is not working. I am getting error as follows:

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\YEAR()
```

But this is not the only mistake in that query .

Answer (score 1):

[`YEAR()` is a mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year), you should use [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) to query this. Like this:

```
->whereRaw('YEAR(docdate) = 2019')
```

---

**Update:**

For your `whereIn()` part, you have to make two queries, one for each column. So you will have to get the correct values from the array. This can be done using `array_map`.

For example:

```
->whereIn('comp', array_map(function($cat) { return $cat['comp']; }, $categories))
->whereIn('cus', array_map(function($cat) { return $cat['cus']; }, $categories))
```

Comment: thank you .. I have error in whereIn('comp, cus', $categories) too even though there is comp and cus in table, it says Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comp, cus'

Comment: I have added an update for the `whereIn` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

---

You can't use whereIn like that, use this way

```
$rslt=Stdetl::whereIn('comp', $categories)
             ->whereIn('cus', $categories)
             ->where(date('Y', strtotime(docdate)), '=', 2019)
              ->get(SUM(number))->toArray();;
```

Comment: I tried like this but it take only first wherein only

Comment: use DB instead      DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('comp', $categories)
             ->whereIn('cus', $categories)->where(date('Y', strtotime(docdate)), '=', 
     2019)->get(SUM(number))->toArray();